# What would happen if you don't use the appropriate kind of delete for a malloc?

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, memory-leaks

I was just wondering what would happen if I did something like this:

```
int main()
{
  char *foo;
  foo = new char[200];
  //do stuff with foo
  delete foo;
}
```

Since foo is allocated as an array, I know that I should use the array `delete[]`, but what would be the effect of the above code? Could this cause a memory leak or some sort of other bad behavior?

Comment: Its unpredictable. It could do anything from "nothing" to making your screen turn blue, to making your speakers start garbling.

Comment: What happens when you borrow money from bank 1 and pay it back to bank 2 instead?

Comment: @icemanind ... or your fridge exploding nowadays ;) ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ -- True. Lets just hope this kind of thing isn't used in something like the Cruz Missile or something

Comment: @icemanind One reason why some embedded systems don't even have a general-purpose heap.

Comment: @icemanind Drones, drones, they're everywhere around and get more and more :-/ ...

Comment: The pointer is declared as `int *`, but the memory is allocated as `new char[]`. This will not even compile.

Comment: @AndreyT woops, typo. let me fix that